# How can i call dynamic object like a function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, dynamic, orchardcms

I am studying orchard architecture.i have faced with a strange concept in display management section. 
in Partial view page there is a 'function call like' syntax like so `Display(Model.Head)`. that is not a function thought, it is a dynamic object defined in orchard WebViewPage.
I am wondering how to define a dynamic object so that you can call it (and pass it an argument as well) like a function as i mentioned.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lighter weight way to do it without clay would be to subclass the built-in [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) class.

```
public static dynamic Display;
void Main()
{
        Display = new MyCallableObject();

        //this is what i was after
        Console.Write(Display("bla bla bla"));     
} 

public class MyCallableObject:DynamicObject
{
     public override bool TryInvoke(InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out Object result)
     {
        result = string.Format("This is response for {0}",args.FirstOrDefault());
        return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it my self!
all the operations have done with Clay Library behind the scene.i have wrote a sample console app for demonstrating the process.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Display = ClayActivator.CreateInstance<MyResponser>(new List<IClayBehavior> {new MyFunctionCallBehavior()});

            //this is what i was after
            Console.Write(Display("bla bla bla"));
        }

    public static dynamic Display;
}


public class MyFunctionCallBehavior : IClayBehavior
{
    public object InvokeMember(Func<object> proceed, object self, string name, INamedEnumerable<object> args)
    {
        return ((MyResponser)self).ResponseForRequest(args.FirstOrDefault().ToString()); 
    }
}

public class MyResponser
{
    public string ResponseForRequest(string param)
    {
        return string.Format("This is response for {0}",param);
    }
}
```